# i am trying to make my first app in fluttet "Error on line 46, column 15: Mapping values are not allowed here. Did you miss a colon earlier?"

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axgw3.png)  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

## STATE MANAGEMENT

mobx: ^2.0.3
flutter_mobx: ^2.0.1
dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter
mobx_codegen: ^2.0.2
build_runner: ^2.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  mobx_codegen: ^2.0.2
  build_runner: ^2.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

try upgrade your package cmd "flutter pub upgrade"

Comment: Put space in mobx_codegen

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert space in front of `mobx_codegen`.

So you pubspec needs to look like this:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  mobx_codegen: ^2.0.2
  build_runner: ^2.2.0
```